# VM just disappeared. Is there a way to restore?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I was using the free trial of the Google Cloud Platform and created a VM to collect some data and save it in a database (locally installed). All this happened during the free trial phase and everything was working fine. I knew the fact that Google will charge me after my free trial phase and for this reason I already entered my billing information in the cloud console website.

When I checked back today, there were no VMs set up, instead there was the button "Enable billing". Even after I clicked this, the VM was not there. It seems like a) billing was never enabled or b) billing was only enabled during the trial phase.

Is there any way on how to recover the VM or is there no chance to get it back at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly enable billing while during the trial, otherwise your instances will be shutted down when the trial runs out.

Comment: Shut down is ok. As far as I remember we enables billing in the system. But they're not only shut down, they're deleted. Is this plausible? Or has someone deleted them?

Comment: @Freddy - that's possible, depending how much time passed since the trial expiration until the billing was enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the information. And I think there's no way to restore it?

Comment: @Freddy -unfortunately, no.

Comment: I just received new information that I wanted to attach for completeness. I quote from Google: "Hello from Google, 

We're attaching a copy of your monthly invoice, detailing your Cloud Platform and APIs activity, for your records. **There's no action required on your part as we'll continue to charge you automatically using the payment info we have on file.**" This is very disappointing.

Comment: @Freddy - was you indeed charged according to the monthly invoice Google provided?

Comment: They put our usage data to the invoice but the added a voucher with the exact same amount so that we got charged $0. I lived under the assumption that after the trial period they just don't add the voucher anymore.

Comment: @Freddy were you able to recover deleted instances? if yes please guide.

Comment: @HafizArslan No, I took the loss and make (more) backups ever since.